# Accessing Controller Command Given a Path in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails is there a way to get a string of the contoller command corresponding to a given path? For example, given route

```
  get 'add_address' => 'locations#new'
```

The code:

```
puts add_address_path.some_method
```

Would output

```
'locations#new'
```

Comment: Is sending some_method relevant to this question?

Comment: I'm looking for the "some_method", which would extract the controller path from the route

Answer (score 0):

Routes are pretty well encapsulated in the routes file, and I'm not sure how you would go about sending a message to an object named after the route to extract the controller and action.

If you're open to an alternative, you could try prying it out with something like this:

```
class MyRouteParser < Struct.new(:named_route)

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def controller
    @parsed[:controller]
  end

  def action
    @parsed[:action]
  end

  def controller_with_action
    "#{controller}\##{action}"
  end

  private

  def parse
    @parsed ||= Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(named_route)
  end
end
```

This would provide the string you want with:

```
route = MyRouteParser.new("add_address_path")
route.controller_with_action

"locations#new"
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response, but I'm having some trouble implementing it. I assume I should put the class in a .rb file, though I don't know exactly where it should go. I tried putting it with the models, but all the "require" methods I run give me the error "cannot load such file". Any suggestions?

Comment: You can put it in the models directory. Just make sure it is named in accordance with Rails convention, which in this example would be my_route_parser.rb. It should be autoloaded and run without issue.

Comment: Also, I'm getting an error " undefined method `full_path' ". Suggestions?

Comment: Yes, sorry. See the corrected solution. Keep in mind that you can call these methods anything you want.  This is just an example.

Comment: BTW, if you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: almost there! I'm getting a "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error for this method when I give the input in the example I posted:

Comment: def controller
    @parsed[:controller]
  end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95358/discussion-between-brent-eicher-and-e-sterling).